# Radio Button not appearing when deployed with Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I am currently developing a web application using ASP.NET 5. The application is complete, however when deploying the application using Microsoft Azure; the radio buttons do not appear. When I run the application on LocalHost the radio button does appear. The attached image shows how the radio button is missing

[Comparison between LocalHost and Azure Deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jqEH.jpg)

I've tried using the radio button with HTML and RAZOR but neither works.

HTML: `<input id="G" type="radio" name="cantidad" value="Extra">Grande`

Razor: `@Html.RadioButton("Grande", new { id = "G", type = "radio", name = "cantidad", value = "Extra" })`

This happens with all radio button in the application.

For some reason the background image also changes when deployed with Azure leading me to believe its something related to the .CSS files.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you share the link to your web application?

Comment: http://fosetopinga.azurewebsites.net/Home/Login

username: admi password: admi

The problem is located on "Crear Combo"

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I just ran the website and noticed an error in developer console on the following line of code - `body onload=fun()`. Basically the problem I am seeing is that this method is not found. Can you check why this is happening? Could it prevent radio buttons to show up? I also noticed some other errors. I would recommend checking for those errors as well. HTH.